# How to Select SQLite table with period in name in python

Tags: sqlite

I added a bunch of pandas dataframes as individual tables to a SQLite database, but I didn't realize one of the names had periods in it. When I tried to `SELECT` and read that table I got this error below:

`pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * from A.J._Doe': near ".": syntax error`

My question: Is there a way to read that table with a period in the name? The other names without the periods work just fine.

```py
name = "A.J._Doe"
pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from " + name, conn)  # Gives the above error message
```

Comment: Try enclosing the table name in backticks:  `SELECT * FROM \`A.J._Doe\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite, you may escape an object name (e.g. table, column, database, etc.) using double quotes, so try:

```
name = "A.J._Doe"
sql = 'SELECT * FROM "' + name + '"'
pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn)
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew there had to be a way to escape that character- I'm new to Python and SQL. Double whammy!